GGPlot line missing form graph
I am using the below code and obtained the following graph. However I would like to dots to be joined by lines to make a line graph but my geom_line code does not seem to be working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
ggplot(data, aes(x= Date, y= Germ)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = Type, linetype = Year)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = Type))+
  labs(x="Burial Weeks", y="% Emergence", colour="", linetype = "Collection Year") +  # Changed legend title
  facet_wrap(~SP) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept=14, lwd=0.5, colour="black") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = pretty_breaks(), limits=c(0,100)) +
  theme_classic()+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("royalblue", "forestgreen"))+
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size=10, face="italic"), 
        legend.position = c(0.85,0.70), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))



As your x variable is categorical you have to map on the group aes, i.e. try geom_line(aes(colour = Type, linetype = Year, group = Type)).

... a second option would be to convert your x variable which represents dates to proper dates.
